# iOS custom keyboard changing constraints

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, keyboard, constraints

I am trying to create a custom keyboard in swift programmatically and have so far been able to create the constraints I want for [portrait](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYY69.png) and [landscape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKOGg.png) on iPhone, but only when I start the keyboard in the respective orientation.

The problem comes when I flip the device myself: [Portrait](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BifRW.png), [Landscape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2My1N.png). I have stored my constraints in two arrays and am running this block of code in my viewDidLoad and viewWillTransition functions:

```
if UIScreen.main.bounds.height >= 568 {
        NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(constraintsLandscape)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(constraintsPortrait)
}
else if UIScreen.main.bounds.height <= 414 {
        NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(constraintsPortrait)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(constraintsLandscape)
}
```

Any help with this is appreciated.

Current [portrait](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PN74u.png) and [landscape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pydKq.png)

Answer (score 1):

if this is inside a method, do u call it after the screen rotates ? if dont you can check device rotation overriding this method:

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
    if UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape {
        print("Device is in Landscape mode")
        NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(constraintsPortrait)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(constraintsLandscape)
    } else {
        print("Device is in Portrait mode")
        NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(constraintsLandscape)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(constraintsPortrait)
    }
}
```

if you are already doing this, then you just need to call `self.view.layoutifNeeded()` after making changes to your constraints.

Comment: Where exactly do I call self.view.layoutIfNeeded() and what do I put in it? And also, nothing is printing when I run your code. Thanks for your quick response though.

Comment: Add it after you change the constraints

Comment: It still doesn't look right. I've included the current screenshots to the question.